# International check in EUR

Tags: check, international

How long does it (usually) take to cash a check in the US from a bank in Italy, in Euros? It is from a big bank, Unicredit.

Comment: Unless you already have the check in your hand, it would be much better to get the Italians to send the money by a money transfer service like Transferwise.  Probably easiest if you set up one of their borderless accounts; the Italians transfer the money to your Euro account (which will be easy for them); you transfer it to your dollar account; you withdraw the dollars.  (No affiliation to Transferwise other than satisfied customer.)

Comment: I wish I had that information sooner, but I already have the check. My bank said they'll cash it, but couldn't tell me how long it would take.

Comment: I have no idea about cashing checks from Italy in the US, but from my limited experience with international transfers, I would say at least a few days. If it's not done within a week, call your bank again and ask what's going on.